# How do I move edit menu items in VS2013 when right clicking on a Code Page

Tags: visual-studio-2012, drop-down-menu, visual-studio-2013, edit

I would like to move my Cut, Copy and Paste menu items up using VS2013 when editing code and right clicking. However, I don't know how to do this.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change a code context menu item (add, remove, move up or down) in Visual Studio:

1. Go to Tools/Customize
2. Click on the Commands tab
3. Select Radio Button named "Context Menu"
4. From Drop down menu select "Editor Context Menus | Code Window"